# Can a Magento 2 extension be use in Adobe Commerce Cloud edition?

Tags: magento2.4, adobe-commerce

Looking for documentation about how to use a Magento 2 extension (not published to a marketplace) with Adobe Commerce Cloud edition.  The plugin currently lives in github.

Is this possible?

Thank you,
Tristan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install any extension to Adobe commerece which is compatible. First of all you need cloud project setup in your local envirnment.Then you need to install module in that project. and deploy your changes. it will be installed on Adobe cloud commerce project.

Official document [Cloud for Adobe Commerce](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/bk-cloud.html)